# DataGrid tab navigation skip column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus, keyboard-navigation, datagridcell

I have a datagrid with template columns in WPF. Couple of columns in the grid are readonly, others on focus become editable (instead of labels, textboxes, checkboxes and such appear).

What I would like to achieve is that the readonly columns are skipped when I am tabbing through the grid's columns.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!
Vladan

---

Nope, not working :(

Here is the complete cell...tried it with KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop and IsTabStop alone...didn't work

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static local:MainWindowResources.gasNameLabel}" Width="*" MinWidth="150" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Name}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataGridTextBoxView}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Have you tried the `Enabled` property or `Focusable` property.  I've never tried either of those on the `DataGrid` but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 14):

Something like this would work:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```